# different meaning of humble

Tags: grammar, british-english, subcontinental-english

As i am new with english can someone explain the meaning of this line ?:

Who that has prided himself on his spiritual strength has not seen it 
humbled to the dust?

Comment: I gave an answer interpreting the sentence as best as I could, but it is a bit difficult without the context. Could you edit your question to include a link to the original text? I may edit my answer if so.

Comment: Interpretation requests (in fact, all criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature) are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying that a person who feels pride in the strength of their spirituality has not come up against a trial suitable to truly test that spirituality. In other words, if a sufficiently awful experience were to befall a person, their spiritual strength would be shaken, and they would no longer express pride in it.

By extension, it implies that no person should hold pride that their spirituality has never been cracked. If they have never been tested to the point that their spirit was shaken, their spirituality has never truly been tested and therefore they are in no place to be prideful.